# json rest api, locally hosted, lan accessible

Tags: json, rest, localhost

For some time now I try to figure it out how to create a json rest api and a database, host it locally and make it accessible in lan. I need this for an android app, exactly to parse data from database to app.
I created the json rest and database usimg XAMP but i didn't figure it out how to make them accessible from lan.
After that somebody recomanded me IIS and since then I did'n figure it out.
Some sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

For the web api application, host in the IIS server in some other system. In the mobile application development environment is in same LAN  network, then call the api using  that web api system ipaddress instead of the localhost.